# Is ZFGC, minimally modified to allow two Quine atoms instead of the empty set, synonymous\bi-interpretable with ZFGC?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Working in $\sf ZFGC$, remove Foundation, stipulate the existence of exactly two Quine atoms. Restrict Separation to fulfillable formulas, i.e. $\{x \in A \mid \phi \}$ exists as long as $\phi$ holds of at least one $x \in A$. And make a similar adjustment on Replacement, so $\{f(x) \mid  x \in A  \}$ exists as long as $f(x)$ exists for at least one $x \in A$. We replace the axiom of Foundation by an axiom asserting the non-existence of descending membership sets all elements of which are not Quine atoms. Formall, this is: $$ \neg \exists h: \forall x \in h \, (\exists y \in h \ (y \in x) \land x \neq \{x\})$$. The theory ought to prove that every set is an element of some $ V_\alpha$ where $V_0 = \{x \mid x=\{x\}\}$, the rest of stages $V_\alpha$ are constructed through iterative powering over $V_0$ in the usual manner.

> Is this theory bi-interpretable with $\sf ZFGC$?

> Is this theory synonymous with $\sf ZFGC$?

**Note:** $\sf GC$ is the axiom of Global Choice, formally stated by adding a new primitive total unary function $C$ to the signature of $\sf ZF$, then axiomatizing:

$\forall x : (\exists y: y \in x) \to C(x) \in x \\\forall x: (\forall y: y \not \in x)\to C(x)=x$

Of course, in the theory defined above $\sf GC$ simply turns to $\forall x: C(x) \in x$.

Comment: Nice question — but this surely isn’t “minimally modified to allow two Quine atoms”, it’s modified to allow two Quine atoms *and banish the empty set!*  The removal of the empty set seems awkward and unmotivated: if you let it remain, the needed modifications are smaller, and the resulting theory becomes nicer in several ways (easier to reason in, and much less dependent on choice/classical logic); and as [paste bee’s answer shows](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462761/2273), it complicates the bi-interpretability proofs for no essentially interesting reason.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, this was done deliberately, there is a reason, its related to Mereological foundation of set theory, where the empty set is not easily captured without somehow disrupting extensionality over the whole medium, if Mereological tenets to be maintained. But, this is another story

Comment: I’ve heard you and others mention this mereological motivation for omitting bottom before, but I’ve never understood it. Can you point me to anywhere it’s really explained/argued properly? It feels to me like (say) arguing that fields should omit 0, because multiplicative inversion is an important operation. Sure, you *can* set up such a theory, bi-interpretable with standard fields, and develop field theory equivalently using it. But it complicates many things and requires accommodations much worse than just making inversion partial; so in hindsight the motivation is just naïve.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, in Mereology having a Bottom atom would violate Supplementation, which is a main tenet of Extensional Mereology. Not only that this anomaly won't be local, it would be infectious since it is pervasive everywhere. Also, it complicates many Mereological systems,  see [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/#AtoOthOpt), also see [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/#UnrCom), Lewis and Leśniewski had rejected bottom, and most Mereologists do. The work of Richard Milton Martin is actually the exception. Lewis's parts of classes also speaks about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sf ZFGC$ is synonymous with the theory you defined, with an additional statement $\varphi$.

Define $x \in' y \Leftrightarrow x \in y$, except if $y$ is $\varnothing$, $\{\varnothing\}$, $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$, or a natural number; make $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ Quine atoms (so $\varnothing \in' \varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\} \in' \{\varnothing\}$), $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ into $0$ (so $x \in' \{\{\varnothing\}\} \Leftrightarrow x \in 0$), and $n$ into $n+1$ ($x \in' n \Leftrightarrow x \in n+1$). Define $C'(x) = C(x)$, except if $x$ is $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ or a natural number; $C'(\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}) = \varnothing$, $C'(\{\{\varnothing\}\}) = C(0)$ and $C'(n) = C(n+1)$ (because the $\in'$ elements of $n$ are the $\in$ elements of $n+1$). Define $\varphi$ as $C(\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}) = \varnothing$.

In the other direction, define $a_1$ as $C'(\{x | x \in' x\})$, and $a_2$ as the Quine atom that is not $a_1$. Define $x \in y \Leftrightarrow x \in' y$, except if $y \in' y$ or $y$ is a natural number; if $y$ is a Quine atom, $x \in y$ iff $x = a_1$ and $y = a_2$, $x \in 0$ iff $x = a_2$, $x \in n+1$ iff $x \in' n$. Define $C(x) = C'(x)$, except if $x$ is $\{a_1,a_2\}$ or a natural number; $C(\{a_1,a_2\})$ is $a_1$ if $\varphi$ is true and $a_2$ otherwise, $C(0) = a_2$, $C(n+1) = C'(n)$.

These definitions are inverses of each other, and the axioms are all equivalent, if we're careful about the construction of $\mathbb{N}$. Define $0$ as $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ (from $\in$) or $\{a_1,a_2\}$ (from $\in'$), and $S(n) = n \cup \{n\}$. None of these transitively contain $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$. We can't quite use these, because they can contain each other, but if we actually use the singletons of these numbers ($\{0\}$, $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$) as the natural numbers, it works. These numbers don't contain $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ or each other, and also aren't $\varnothing$, $\{\varnothing\}$, $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$, or Quine atoms, so all of the elements of natural numbers are completely unchanged (except the Quine atoms). This implies that Foundation is still true, and also that which natural number a set is (or whether it is a natural number at all) will not be "unexpectedly" changed.

The theory you defined is synonymous with itself with an additional statement $\varphi$. Define $C''(x) = C'(x)$, except $C''(\{0,1\})$ is $0$ if $\varphi$ is true and $1$ otherwise, and $C''(\{n+1,n+2\}) = C'(\{n,n+1\}) + 1$. In the other direction, define $C'(x) = C''(x)$, except $C'(\{n,n+1\}) = C''(\{n+1,n+2\}) - 1$, and define $\varphi \Leftrightarrow C'(\{0,1\}) = 0$. These definitions are inverses of each other. (This paragraph could be "merged" into the previous ones, to avoid having to define a third global choice function $C''$, but I think it's probably easier this way...?)

So your theory is synonymous with $\sf ZFGC$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saying that to the theory I defined you add an axiom that the empty set exists? This cannot be done since the modified Foundation axiom forbids it. It is a theorem of this theory that the empty set doesn't exist.

Comment: ...Oh, I see. My answer is completely wrong then.

Comment: I've changed it a bit, I think it should work now.

Comment: You have an empty set for the alternative membership, lets denote it $\in^*$, you defined, that is $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$, this is $\in^*$-empty, but this contradict my theory. So, you must have a plan to get rid of that set, but I don't see that clearly. You say the set $\varnothing$ becomes $\{0\}$, but why? I thought you need to turn $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ so $\{0\}$. The exposition is not very clear to me.

Comment: There are three different membership operations; let's call them $\in_1$, $\in_2$, $\in_3$. $x \in_3 y$ iff $x \in_2 y$, unless $y$ is either the set with no $\in_2$-elements, or the singleton of a natural number. $x \in_3 \varnothing$ iff $x = 0$, so with $\in_3$ there is no empty set. $x \in_3 \{n\}$ iff $x = n+1$. (I should probably rewrite the answer instead of just putting all these details in a comment).

Comment: I think the approach is a little bit twisted, you don't need to represent the empty set nor need to modify the modified Foundation as to allow empty sets. What you need to let $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ be sent to the set $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$, and the later to the set $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\} , \{\{\varnothing\}\} \}$, and this in turn to be sent to the set $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{ \{\varnothing\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\} \} \}$ and so in an alternate matter.

Comment: The main reason I did it like this was to avoid having to do all of the reshuffling at once because it would be hard to follow. It... seems to have made it *harder* to follow instead of easier. (Also originally I hadn't noticed that the theory proved $\varnothing$ didn't exist.)

Comment: When we turn $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ to $0$, the problem is that it is already in the transitive closure of $0$. Since we are keeping $\in$ otherwise, then this would violate Foundation for $ \in'$, isn't it?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar It depends on how you construct the natural numbers. I've edited the answer with more details on a construction that I think should work.