# Can this kind of Mereology be synonymous with Set Theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, mereology

This question is about synonymy of Morse-Kelley set theory "$\sf MK$" with the following Mereological theory:

Language: first order logic with equality. Extra-logical primitives: $\subseteq$ standing for the binary relation "*is a part of*", and a partial unary function symbol $\{\}$ standing for "*is the label of*", or can also be read as "*is the singleton of*".

Extra-logical Axioms:

**Parthood:** $x \subseteq x \\ x \subseteq y \subseteq x \to x=y \\ x \subseteq y \subseteq z \to x \subseteq z$

**Supplmentation:** $y\not \subseteq x \to \exists z \subseteq y: \neg z \ O \ x$

*Define:* $\operatorname{atom}(x) \iff \forall y \subseteq x \, (y=x)$

**Atomicity:** $\forall x \, \exists \text{ atom } y: y \subseteq x  $

**Composition:** $\exists z: \varphi, \to \exists x \, \forall \text{ atom } y \,( y \subseteq x \leftrightarrow \exists z: \varphi(z) \land y \subseteq z); \text{ if } x \text { is not free in } \varphi$

*Define:* $(x= \mathcal S \, y: \varphi) \iff \forall \text{ atom } y \,( y \subseteq x \leftrightarrow \exists z: \varphi(z) \land y \subseteq z)$

**Labeling:** $\{x\}=\{y\} \to x=y$

**Purity:** $ \exists x \, (y=\{x\}) \leftrightarrow \operatorname{atom}(y)$

**Start:** $\exists a \, \exists b: a \neq b \land \forall x \,( x=\{x\} \leftrightarrow x=a \lor x = b)$

**Foundation:** $ \forall x (\exists \{x\} \subseteq h \to x \ O  \ h ) \to \exists a \subseteq h: a=\{a\}$

**Replacement:** $\varphi(a,b) \land \varphi (c,d) \to [a=c \leftrightarrow b=d] \\ \varphi(a,b) \to \operatorname {atom}(a) \land \exists l: l=\{b\} \\ A = \mathcal S \, a: \exists b \, ( \varphi(a,b)  )  \\ B= \mathcal S \, b: \exists a \, ( \varphi(a,b)  ) \\ \to \\ \exists l: l=\{A\} \leftrightarrow \exists l: l= \{B\} $

*Define:* ${\sf Q}= \mathcal S \, a: a=\{a\}$

**Abundance:** $\exists l: l= \{{\sf Q}\}$

**Infinity:** $\exists x: x \not \subseteq {\sf Q} \land \exists l: l=\{x\} \land \forall y: \{y\} \subseteq x \to \{\{y\}\} \subseteq x$

**Choice:** $\exists C \, \forall x \, \exists y : y=C(x) \land  \exists \{y\} \subseteq x$

This theory does respect all tenets of Mereology, the first four principles are the axioms of Atomic General Extensional Mereology "$\sf AGEM$". Define set membership $\in$ as:

$$x \in y \iff \exists z \subseteq y: z=\{x\}  $$

Call the collection of all sentences written in $\sf FOL(=,\in)$ over the whole domain of this theory (i.e. all quantifiers unrestricted) that are provable in this theory as "$\sf MMK$", standing for "Mereological $\sf MK$".

It should be made clear that $\sf MMK$ proves the non-existence of an empty set, minimally breaches Foundation, and that it is fully extensional.

> Is $\sf MMK$ synonymous with $\sf MK$?

> Is $\sf MK$ synonymous with this theory?

This question is related to the question "[Is ZFGC, minimally modified to allow two Quine atoms instead of the empty set, synonymous\bi-interpretable with ZFGC?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462747/95347)", and I was hoping that the positive [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462761/95347) to it can be extended to the case here.

Note: "$ O $" stands for the overlap relation (i.e. existence of a common part), and "$\mathcal S \, a: \varphi$" stands for "*the sum of all atoms realizing $\varphi$*". The expression "$\exists \{x\} \subseteq y$" stands for "$\exists z: z=\{x\} \land z \subseteq y$".

Comment: Supplementation is the wrong way around. If $x = \mathbb{N}$ and $y = {0}$, then no subset of $y$ is disjoint from $x$, but there are subsets of $x$ that are disjoint from $y$.

Comment: @pastebee, Thanks! I've corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, for every atom $a$, $a \subseteq x$ implies $a \subseteq y$, then $x \subseteq y$. Assume $x \nsubseteq y$, then by Supplementation, there is a $z \subseteq x$ such that $\neg z \ O \ y$. By Atomicity, there is an atom $a \subseteq z \subseteq x$, and $a \nsubseteq y$ because $\neg zOy$, contradicting the assumption that if $a \subseteq x$ then $a \subseteq y$.

This implies that the usual definition $a \subseteq b \iff \forall x (x \in a \Rightarrow x \in b)$ and your definition of $\in$ from $\subseteq$ are inverses of each other, so it does not matter whether the language is $\in$ or ($\subseteq$, $\{\}$); your mereological theory is synonymous with $\sf MMK$.

MMK and MK are not synonymous. A model of MK has no nontrivial definable automorphisms, but any model of MMK has a definable automorphism by swapping the two Quine atoms. If they were synonymous, then a model of MK would also be a model of MMK (with a different $\in$), and therefore have a nontrivial definable automorphism, which is impossible. (A similar argument might work to prove they are not bi-interpretable, but I'm not sure of the details). So the issue is that we can't distinguish the two Quine atoms. (The reason this argument didn't work in the case of ZFGC was the global choice function $C$, which can be used to pick one of the Quine atoms; in MMK, while choice functions do exist, there isn't a choice of one particular one that an isomorphism has to preserve).

If we add a constant $q$ and the axiom $q \in q$ (so that we can distinguish the Quine atoms), the resulting theory is synonymous with MK, by a similar argument to [my previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462761/508667), except we use $q$ to remember which Quine atom was the empty set.

Comment: Thank you! As regards Infinity you are right, this I missed to add, I'll correct it. But this theory proves the power set axiom. So, after all it is not synonymous with MK because we cannot distinguish between the two atoms, that we need to add a constant to do that. Actually, that's what I wanted to really know.

Comment: but why we cannot fix a specific global choice function, and work your older argument in reference to it? Also, another way if we add a constant function standing for global choice instead of adding a primitive constant denoting one of the Quine atoms, would that work to achieve synonymy.

Comment: How does it prove power set? And which of the axioms is false in my "hereditarily countable sets" model?

Comment: Adding a constant function for global choice would make it synonymous with "MK with a constant function for global choice", by applying my earlier argument. I don't know if that's synonymous with MK, but I think it probably isn't.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar The issue is that we can't just "fix a specific global choice function". None of them are definable, in particular we can't definably choose one of the Quine atoms. Also, my argument doesn't just require a particular global choice function; it requires the fact that the global choice function the interpretation is given (as $C$) is the one defined by the other interpretation, in order to get back out encoded information, and ensure that the interpretations are inverses of each other.

Comment: Power set axiom is provable from Replacement. Let $x$ be labeled (i.e. $\exists l: l=\{x\}$). Now, $\mathcal P(x)$ is the totality of all labels of parts of $x$, clearly $x$ is the sum of all atoms of its parts, and we have $l=\{y\} \land l \subseteq \mathcal P(x)  \land y \subseteq x$ is 1-to-1, so by Replacement $\mathcal P(x)$ must be labeled. $\square$. In a similar way you can prove Set Unions.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar "clearly $x$ is the sum of all atoms of its parts" I don't see why this is true. If $x$ is $\mathbb{N}$, then the set of even numbers is one of its parts, but the set of even numbers is not a natural number, so the label of the set of even numbers is not part of $x$. If you mean that $x$ is the union of all of its parts that are atoms, that's true but doesn't seem helpful, it just means you'd end up with the set of all atoms that are part of $x$, which is not the power set.

Comment: I feel like at least one of us is making mistakes because of the mereological language, which at least for me is not something I'm used to. Is the set-theoretic statement "for any set $A$, $\{b : \exists a \in A \exists c (\varphi(a,c) \land b \in c)\}$ is a set" equivalent? (assuming $\varphi$ acts like a function and always "outputs" sets)

Comment: In atomic Mereology every object is a sum of its atoms, this is like saying every class is the union of all singleton subsets of it. When it is said a set is the sum of atoms of its parts, is like saying every class is the union of all singleton subsets of subsets of it; that is, $x= \bigcup \{ y \mid \exists z \subseteq x:  y \subseteq z \land \exists k (y=\{k\}) \}$. Now, the sum of all labels of parts of $x$ is in set theoretic terms the class union of all singletons of subclasses of $x$, which is the power class of $x$,

Comment: the formula I mentioned would send every singleton of a subclass of $x$ to its element, and so it is one-to-one relation, now clearly $x$ is the sum of all atoms of its parts, by replacement since $x$ is labeled then, its power class must be labeled too. In set theoretic terms: we have one-to-one relation between the class of all singletons of subclasses of $x$ and the power class of $x$, since the set union of the later is $x$ itself, and $x$ do have a label, then the set union of the former must be labeled, this is saying the power class of $x$ must have a label.

Comment: ...Oh, I see now. I had missed that the Replacement axiom was a biconditional. In the hereditarily countable sets, if $A$ is labelled then $B$ is labelled, but the converse isn't always true.

Comment: You see there is a sense in which Mereology enables strong visualization into internal set structures, and sometimes can enable mush consize arguments. Anyhow, I'm seeing the problem here. I don't want to add a primitive to the language, but could this be fixed if we add a quine atom, and a self membered set that is not equal to the quine atom that contains the quine atom as it's only non-self element, i.e. we have $a=\{a\}$ and $b=\{\mathcal S \,
x: x=a \lor x=b \}$ where $b\neq a$; then we stipulate that only those can breach foundation. Now, those are definable!

Comment: Yep, that's synonymous with MK. The specifics of the argument are a little different (now $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$, which is $\{b\}$, is unchanged, and $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, which would be $\{a,b\}$, has to become something else, since $b = \{a,b\}$) but it's the exact same idea, and indeed the fact that they're definably different means we can just say $a$ corresponds to $\varnothing$ and not get any problems.